# Mongoose: How can I access a select:false property in a schema method?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Quick code:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: {type: String, select: false}
});

userSchema.methods.checkPassword = function(password, done) {
    console.log(password);      // Password to check
    console.log(this.password); // stored password
    ...
};
```

I don't want the password to be accessible by default, but I need a method to check against a user inputted password before authenticating the user. I know I can do a query to the DB to include these values, but I'm a bit lost on how I could access the hidden property on the schema method itself. `this` in the method itself is just the returned query, so it seems like it is inaccessible? Should I be doing the `checkPassword()` function elsewhere?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use `select` to select password in query. This is an example query.

```
User.findOne().select('password').exec(callback);
```

And this must be what you want to check password.

```
userSchema.methods.checkPassword = function(password, done) {
    User.findOne({username: this.username}).select('password').exec(function (err, user) {
        if (user.password == password)
            return true;
        else 
            return false;
    });
}
```

I hope this might help you.

Comment: So it seems it's not possible to access the `select:false` properties from within a `schema.methods` itself, you have to pass it to a callback. Got it! Thank you.

Comment: @Khay, I am getting an error that `find().select is not a function`

Comment: @PulkitAggarwal please check your schema name which you are using for `find()`. There may be typo error in it.

Comment: Is it possible to select multiple fields. For example `const user = await User.findOne({ email }).select(
    'emailVerified',
    'password'
  );`

Comment: @Ashik See answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73121876/11322237

Answer (score 14):

You can explicitly allow the password field (with {select:"false"}) to be returned in your find call **with "+" operator before field** e.g.:

```
User.findOne({}).select("+password") // "+" = allow select hidden field
```

Comment: "+" operator is useful if you need property in addition to the rest of the properties. otherwise, it just returns that property excluding all others.

Answer (score 0):

A right way is writing the fields on method findOne. You can ask the fields that you want to return. In your case, it should be:

```
await User.findOne({ username: this.username }, 'password').exec();
```

Documentation:
[mongoose.findOne](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne)

Answer (score 0):

Above answers only show selection for a single property.

For multiple properties, syntax is this one:

```js
await this.userModel
      .findOne({ email }, { status: 1, firstName: 1, religion: 1 })
      .exec();
```

This will return:

```js
{
  _id: new ObjectId("62de5a5158b809468b812345"),
  status: 'Active',
  firstName: 'John',
  religion: 'Christian Orthodox'
}
```