# How can I get a `select: false` Schema objects value from the context of this in a schema.methods method?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

tl;dr: If this isn't possible and `User.findOne({username: this.username}).select('token')` is the only way, then please let me know. Otherwise, I would like to know if there's another way to select `select:false` objects.

---

I have an email verification token that I only want to pull from my UserSchema object when an email verification endpoint is visited. (Other than that, I don't even necessarily want the object to exist in the database, but I don't know of a way to make a temporary value.) Inside of the context of this within a mongoose method, how can I select this value?

I also want to do the same thing for the password

Example:

```js
const userSchema = new Schema({
    username: {
        //unique: true,
        required: true,
        type: String
    },
    password: {
        required: true,
        type: String,
        select: false
    },
    email: {
        required: true,
        type: String,
        unique: true
    },
    phone: {
        required: true,
        type: String
    },
    name: {
        first: { 
            required: true,
            type: String
         },
        last: { 
            required: true,
            type: String
        },
        full: { 
            required: true,
            type: String,
            default: function() {
                return `${this.name.first} ${this.name.last}`
            }
        },
    },
    email_verified: {
        required: true,
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    token: {
        type: String,
        select: false
    },
    active: {
        required: true,
        type: Boolean,
        default: true
    },
    created_date: {
        required: true,
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    updated_date: {
        required: true,
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
    }
},
{
    timestamps: { 
        createdAt: 'created_date', 
        updatedAt: 'updated_date' 
    }
})
```

Methods in same file:

```js
/* Code in question */
userSchema.methods.verify = async function(submittedToken, cb) {
 try {
        let user = this

        /* I've tried this.select() and this.get() to no avail, seems like those only work with user.findOne() which I don't mind using, but would like to avoid if I can use this instead */
         const token = user.token //undefined because of select:false
         if(token != submittedToken) return cb({'Invalid token'})
         return cb(null, user)
    } catch (err) {
         return cb(err, false);
    }
}

userSchema.methods.authenticate = function(submittedPassword, cb) {
    bcrypt.compare(submittedPassword, this.password, function(err, isMatch) {
        if (err) return cb(err);
        return cb(null, isMatch)
    });
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)
```

On a side note, do you guys recommend leaving the userId out of the email verification endpoint? It makes it easier to select the user, but not sure if it will cause security issues.
Total noob with Mongoose and not even sure if I'm approaching this professionally or securely, so all pointers welcome. Thanks guys.

Comment: I'm not a Mongoose expert, but I think the answer is "no, you can't do that". AFAICT, `this` won't have the field(s) that you're after based on the `select: false` configuration. And the `.select()` method seems to be something that is applied against a `Query` rather than an instance of the model. Your question may be a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28838640/mongoose-how-can-i-access-a-selectfalse-property-in-a-schema-method)

Comment: Thank you, I'll go that route. Also, is it bad practice to require a userId in the email verification token endpoint? Not sure if it raises security concerns. Seems like a better idea to leave it out, but it's easier to find the user and keeps endpoints consistent when leaving it in.